# Find the six matrices using the linear transformation $T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

$T : M_{2 \times 2} \to M_{2 \times 2}$ is a linear transformation. $T (B) = ABC$ . Here $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $C = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ .

We consider two different bases in $ M_{2 \times 2}$.

$X = \{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$  , $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$  , $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$  } .

$Y = \{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$  , $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$  , $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$  } .

I have to find the matrices $S , S^{-1} , H , J$ of order $4 \times 4$.

Here $S[B_{ X}] = [B_Y]$ , $S^{-1}[B_Y ] = [B_{ X}]$ , $H[B_X] = [T(B)_Y]$ ,  $J(B_Y) = [T(B)_X]$

Can anyone please help me to find these matrices. I am really clueless because I do not know most of the notations?

Comment: Then the first thing to do is to find the notations. Do you not have some study materials where they are defined? OK: $B_X$ means the representation of $B$ with respect to the basis $X$, that is, if I call the four elements of $X$ $R,S,T,U$ and $B=aR+bS+cT+dU$ then $B_X$ is the vector $(a,b,c,d)$. Similarly for $B_Y$.

Comment: How are you coming along on finding the definitions?

Comment: Have you given up?